# window open IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open

what is the right use of window.open in IE8?

```
window.open('prova.php','prova','width=350,height=250');
```

is good in firefox but not in IE8

Comment: The Syntax is the same. Do you have a popup blocker enabled?

Comment: Is IE8 perhaps blocking this attempt as a popup?

Comment: Is your example *over simplified*? in IE the following will fail. `window.open('someUrl','name with spaces','someFeatures');` e.g. the 2nd parameter MUST not contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` works across browsers. And your code works fine for me in IE8 too. It could be some other reason like your pop-up is being blocked, check the settings just in case.

Check out:

- [Learn to Disable Internet Explorer 8’s Top 3 Most Annoying Alerts](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/53124.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a native popup blocker. You have to manually enable popups. You can try NOT using window.open and instead inject html in the form of a modal in the page.